# JanusGraph how to override Vertex if exists

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am looking into janusgraph over cassandra. One trouble I am having do I configure primary key on janusgraph such it does an upsert rather than create duplicates.

Any help on how do it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but there is not a feature in JanusGraph specifically that will cause an insert operation (e.g. `g.addV('foo')` to perform an upsert instead of a direct insert.  To achieve upsert functionality, you can use the `mergeV()` and `mergeE()` steps that were added as part of TinkerPop 3.6 and are supported by JanusGraph (currently supports 3.6.3).  These steps perform in an "update if exists or create if not" type manner.  This will allow you to specify the unique element values to match on and the property values to set in the create or update cases.